# Is there a way to watch times with moment.js and run a function when it does?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm new to moment.js and javascript and I couldn't seem to find anything in moment.js documentation or other questions here. I am comparing two different times, and would like to watch the time and run a function when Time A is equals to Time B.
so something like:

```
    var a = TimeA
    var b = TimeB
    //watch the current time 
    when a === b {
   //run a function
        }   
 else {
//do nothing
}
```

Comment: What are these times? Could you give us a real world example?

Comment: I have one time of login which is in both an epoch and HH:mm:ss format and another time thats just set as the current time(in epoch format). Basically I want to have it structured where if the time of login is, for example, 2 hours ago, run a function that sets an alert.

Comment: `for example` ... No we cannot give a good advice based on such vague descriptions ... Please [edit] your question to show what you are actually trying to do, and give some sample inputs and what you've tried already.

Comment: @JonasWilms  I have a node cron running every 30 min and it should execute a function at 6 am for all time zones we are dealing with. So if it is not 6 am at a timezone then data with that time zone will be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this. But the most traditional way is to use an Interval Function as Badgy has pointed. Here is an working example for a 1 second interval:

```js
var timeA = moment().add(10, 'seconds'); // 10 seconds from now

var tmr = setInterval(()=>{
  var now = moment().unix();
  var then = timeA.unix();
  console.log(now, then)
  if (now >= then) {
      clearInterval(tmr);
      console.log('Whatever you want to do');      
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I used .unix() method in moment.js because it returns the time in seconds. So it's better for comparison with the first time than a string like '2013-02-04T22:44:30.652Z' or the isSame() method because it uses milliseconds and can skip the exact moment. A second is a large enough time unit so it can be compared to the current time.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a [interval function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and check every second if the times equal each other. Also throw a look [at this](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) it may help too.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up setting up an interval function to check every second if the unix value of my two times matched, and it worked.